# How to add list of figures and list of tables to the table of content with R markdown and bookdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, bookdown

I have a report (pdf output) where I want to add bibliography, list of figures and list of tables to the appendix. And I want those three elements to appear in the table of content.

I add the *bibliography* by adding `bibliography: bibliography.bib` to my yaml header. The list of figures and the list of tables I add with LaTex directly.

My appendix therefore looks like:

```
# Literature {-}

\listoffigures

\listoftables
```

This *nearly* works: bibliography, list of figures and list of tables are rendered correctly.

**The only problem is, the table of content does only show an entry *Literature*. The list of figures and list of tables does not appear.**

**How can I fix this?**

---

*I tried with `lof: yes` and `lot: yes` in various places of the yaml header (idea from [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/publishers.html) as well as with `toc_appendix: yes` (from the same source)*

What am I missing?

---

My complete header looks like:

```
---
title: something
header-includes: \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{float} \usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{framed} \usepackage{longtable} \definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{240,240,240} \pagenumbering{roman} \usepackage{caption} \captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    fig_caption: yes
    highlight: kate
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
date: | 
    |  
    | `r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`
documentclass: report
geometry: margin=1in
fontfamily: mathpazo
fontsize: 11pt
bibliography: bibliography.bib
preamble: |
  % Any extra latex you need in the preamble
---
```

Comment: Using `---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
toc: yes
lof: yes
lot: yes
---` with each parameter in its own line works fine for me.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer: Thx for your reply. That was my first try as well. Weirdly I get an error: `Error in base_format(toc = toc, number_sections = number_sections, fig_caption = fig_caption,  : 
  unused arguments (lof = TRUE, lot = TRUE)`. Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer: I added my header for completeness. I tried inserting `lof: yes` and `lot: yes` just underneath `toc: yes` without success. I also changed `pdf_book` to `pdf_document2` without success.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Strange, I can reproduce the error. Looks like a bug?

Comment: The problem ist the document class. If you delete this line, it works. If you need to use the report document class, add `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` to your includes.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer: Thx again. I still get the same error when I delete the document class line.. any other ideas?

Comment: No. I just tried it again on another machine and I only added the tex package `tocbibind` and I got LoT, LoF and then my section References added to the ToC.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer: Thank you so much, I got it to work now! :) I had to add `usepackage{tocbibind}` to the yaml header. Somehow I still have to include the two sections with `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` in my appendix. (`lof: yes` and `lot: yes` still throw the same error). But that's fine for me. Happy it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies with the document class report. I guess that it does not handle the list of tables or list of figures like the article class does.

A simple solution is to add `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` to your document. The package does exactly what you want - it adds both appendix sections to your table of contents. You still have to manually add them at the end of your document using `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`.