# List of figures is not working in R markdown

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I have an rmarkdown document with both plots and tables.  I added both a \listoffigures and a \listoftables at the top of my document.  When I knit it to a pdf, I get the list of tables but nothing but the heading for the list of figures.

What does list of figures grab to make its list?  I had to add captions to the table and these are what gets picked up in the List of Tables.  I have a title on my plot, but maybe that is not what List of Figures is looking for?

I created a reproducible example.

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "me"
date: "12/24/2020"
output: pdf_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
```

```
\listoffigures

\listoftables

\newpage
```

```
ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_point(aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  ggtitle("This is a test")
```

```
\newpage
```

```
kbl(head(mpg), booktabs = T, caption = "Another Test")
```

This generates a three page pdf.  The first page with the title, a blank List of Figures and a List of Tables showing the Another Test table on page 3.

Anyone know why that List of Figures is not working here?  I have tried everything I can think of or find online to get it to work.

Comment: A simple solution is to add `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` to your document

Comment: I tried using both `ggtitle()` and `lab()` to add the title.  Neither works.  My actual plots have captions on them as well which appear as footnotes.  This is not picked up by List of Figures either.

Comment: Could you try with `{r,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,,fig.cap="Figure 1: My text.\\label{plot01}",fig.pos='H',fig.align='center',out.width='100%',fig.height=7,fig.width=7}` in your chunck?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use this?  I tried just adding it to my code and I am now getting a LaTeX error message.  Something about it only being able to use it in the preamble?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637936/how-to-add-list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables-to-the-table-of-content-with-r-mar

Comment: This works but it is putting the figure caption from the chunk heading and not the title from the plot.  In the interest of keeping this a minimal example, just adding the `fig.cap = "This is a test"` works.  The rest is unrelated to this issue.  What is the `\\label(plot01)` supposed to be doing?  It does not appear to have any impact on what gets printed out.

Comment: What  LOF should list? You have included an image, not a figure. As the above comment pointed, you only nedd add a caption in the R chunk options to solve this.   On the other,  it is better use  `lof:yes` in YALM header than ` \listoffigures`.